# Using External Binary Resource

Tags: c++, qt

I'm on a project that used to have Compiled-in Resources.

Now, the user can choose the theme that he wants to work on. No problems until there, in a little research I started to use the [External Binary Resource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#external-binary-resources) approach.

My resources were build successfully and the `QResource::registerResource("/path/to/myresource.rcc");` returns true.

It is not working properly though. Apparently the compiled-in resource is still there, in the executable. I can't see the different icons stored in my external binary resource.

How do I remove this compiled-in resource? Do I need to do that to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `.pro` file for your project, you need to remove the resource file from the `RESOURCES` list. If you still want it to be listed in your project, you can use `OTHER_FILES`.

*Before:*

```
RESOURCES += file1.qrc file2.qrc
```

*After:*

```
RESOURCES += file2.qrc
OTHER_FILES += file1.qrc
```

If you want to go a step further you can automate the build of qrc files:

```
RCC_BINARY_SOURCES += file1.qrc

asset_builder.commands = $$[QT_HOST_BINS]/rcc -binary ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} -no-compress
asset_builder.depend_command = $$[QT_HOST_BINS]/rcc -list $$QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
asset_builder.input = RCC_BINARY_SOURCES
asset_builder.output = $$OUT_PWD/$$DESTDIR/${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}.qrb
asset_builder.CONFIG += no_link target_predeps
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += asset_builder

OTHER_FILES += $$RCC_BINARY_SOURCES
```

Comment: this creates individual rcc files for each qrc. How do we tell it to create one single rcc for multiple qrc's like what happens with cmake : qt_add_binary_resources(resources x.qrc y.qrc OPTIONS -no-compress) results in the following rcc invocation by cmake : rcc -no-compress --binary --name resources --output /Users/xxx/code/roku-qml/app/build/resources.rcc /Users/xxx/code/roku-qml/app/x.qrc /Users/xxx/code/roku-qml/app/y.qrc

Comment: @n-mam You should post your own question. Anyway, looking at the `combine` CONFIG option of qmake should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the way the resources are compiled. By default, every resource file (`resources.qrc`, for example) included in a Qt project is *compiled* to C++ code (the `qrc_resources.cpp` you've probably seen after compiling the project). That makes the resource is compiled and linked with your executable (or library). The Qt for Visual Studio plugin does exactly that: adds a custom build step to every QRC file. Open the properties of the QRC file to take a look (right-click on the QRC file, then *Properties*):

[image: Default compilation of a QRC file]

- Command line: `"$(QTDIR)\bin\rcc.exe" -name "%(Filename)" -no-compress "%(FullPath)" -o .\GeneratedFiles\qrc_%(Filename).cpp`
- Outputs: `.\GeneratedFiles\qrc_%(Filename).cpp`
- `%(Filename)` is, as you can figure out, the extension-less name of the file

To avoid this behaviour just remove the QRC file from the project. Of course, the problem is that you'll have to manually build the `.rcc` file. You can do it using a script as part of your makefile.

On the other hand, if you're using Visual Studio, you can change the command used to compile it, adding the `-binary` option to the `rcc` tool so it compiles to an external file. In this way it will be included in your usual compilation workflow:
[image: Custom compilation of QRC to RCC]

- Command line: `"$(QTDIR)\bin\rcc.exe" -name "%(Filename)" "%(FullPath)" -binary -o "%(Outputs)"`
- Outputs: `$(OutDir)\%(Filename).rcc` - it is different from screenshot because I took it from an existing project, use the one in the text to place the RCC file in the same dir of your executable.

Important note: be sure you change the build tool for all the configurations.

If you use a makefile or Qt Creator instead, you can use this as a base to create the needed script.

Hope this can help you.